# Compressing many commits into fewer, but larger, commits

Tags: git

I git-commit everything I do every hour. This is nice but I end up with way too many commits.

I'd like to be able to purge this so that instead of :

```
1 hour ago
2 hours ago
.
23 hours ago
24 hours ago
```

I just have something like:

```
1 hour ago
2 hours ago
1 day ago
7 days ago
```

etc.

Currently each hour I do:

```
git-add .
git-commit -a
```

How can I remove certain commits? I don't want to undo any changes. I just don't care to have quite so many points to revert to. I'd like to have a lot of commits for the past few hours but then only a few after that (the past day, week, month, etc. or other major points that I keep on purpose).

Comment: Why are you committing every hour? You should be committing after every logical change and then rebase when done to get rid of your mistakes in the history.

Comment: @mathepic: Committing often with git is a very good practice. As answered below, you can later rebase your commits so that you don't have so many. Committing often allows you to go back in case you start adding small changes that later end up being a total failure. You can step back and restart at a better point.

Comment: To add…commit logical changes, and use more [meaningful commit messages](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/3308646748/writing-git-commit-messages)

Comment: @Erik Committing based on time is never a good practice. You have to completely re-edit your history instead of just move & squash commits.

Comment: i must confess that i'm using git for general backups. i know many people are against this but like all good unix tools git is very flexible and is serving my needs nicely (i'm actually doing commits every 15 minutes but was too ashamed to admit it!). once i get rebase mastered I think I'll have a decent little backup system. i still do rsync's each day for "real" backups (system-wide). but git is working great for what i need for personal backups.

Comment: @James - In the case you are using it for please be sure to use `squash` on the commits in `git rebase -i`. If you delete commits - the changes that you made in those commits are discarded. If you `squash` them, the change sets will be merged and you will maintain proper backups.

Comment: "Commit often" (as Erik says) and "commit after every logical change (as mathepic says) are not mutually exclusive. You should try to code in such a way that you reach the end of a logical change as frequently as possible, so that your commits are both nice and logical, as well as frequent. That said, `git rebase -i` is nice to have around when you need it.

Comment: Why do you commit every hour? You should commit every minute ;) (on a more serious note, I commit as frequently as needed as to be able to post small commit messages)

Answer (score 29):

Have a look at the [`git rebase -i`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode) command. This lets you 'squash' commits into larger ones, which seems like what you want to do.

Comment: For a text version of how to squash commits with rebase: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

Answer (score 0):

Using `git rebase -i` with the `squash` is an simple way of doing this. However this requires user-interaction.

If you're doing this all the time, you may want to think about writing either a git commit hook for yourself (see [Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)), or just a normal script that you can choose to run when you want. If I had more time I would write it out for you.  It seems worth the invested time to automate this more for yourself.

To do this without user interaction, you'd need to avoid `git rebase -i`. In that case, something like `git reset --soft` might be what you're looking for (see [Git Reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) for more info). If you ran this as a pre-commit hook, you could check to see if the last commit was yesterday (see below for info on listing the commits by date). If the last commit was yesterday, this would tell you its time to collapse the commits into a single commit. Once you've `git reset --soft` to the first commit performed yesterday, you could re-commit all of those changes. Remember that you'd have to specify the original authored date using the `--date` option of `git commit`, so that the collapsed commit keeps its old date.

From https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats you can create a list of the your most recent commits for parsing, based on the date the commit was originally authored. For example, the following shows how you would create a list of the last 4 commits. I chose 4 just as an example, you may want to choose a number that ensures you see all of the previous days commits, depending on your repo, you may want to list all commits and reorganize your entire history.

```
git log --format="%H %ar" | head -n 4
```

The output looks like this:

```
6c3c5d3970c9f7de9e762f7e8300eaa37db11363 19 hours ago
2e1a8020f59be0cf43500a86033e2acde0707961 2 days ago
9bc3479a257e3f7f9dc9cbb88f3723706369b160 2 days ago
b26353b764cdd3bce0e7f0dec90ea84127c4b292 2 days ago
```

I'm not sure if it would be easier to parse the list if its listed with relative dates or a different date format.

Also, I realized that if you write this as a pre-commit hook, you would have to `git stash` your current working directory temporarily, manage your history, they restore what you stashed.