# How to remove local commits history from what you push to origin in GIT?

Tags: git

I'm new to Git,

I do development on a local host and do frequent commits, however, I don't want all this commit history to be shown when I push to origin. How to I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compressing many commits into fewer, but larger, commits.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218184/compressing-many-commits-into-fewer-but-larger-commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [rebase](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) and [squash your commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250238/collapsing-a-git-repositorys-history).

Answer (score 0):

I don't internals of git but following works for me.

```
git reset --hard <SHA of commit one commit before your first local commit > ( If commit order is RA-B-C if B and C are local commits RA is SHA you have to give) 

git merge --squash ORIG_HEAD

git commit
```

It will be great if someone can explain this.